# building startup project when dependent project is modified

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two projects-

- Parent
- Child

Parent is not referencing Child at compile time but will be needing at runtime. So I put post-build event in Parent project to copy "output directory of Child" to Parent output directory in bin/debug/Children/Child1/*.*

Now when do I change something in Child project and hit F5, visual studio build child project but not the parent project. And hence output of Child is not copied to Parent's and it is not debuggable. I have to clean-build/rebuild every time I change something in Child.

So what is the way to achieve this.

**UPDATE**

So I have put a dependency in solution file. So that when I build Parent it builds child automatically. And startup project is Parent. Still change in child only build child and not Parent.

Comment: I think you can set it as a build dependency manually.

Comment: do a rebuild from the solution is what I would try first.. and make sure that that the child project is not marked as the statup project..

Comment: I have updated the question @MethodMan

Comment: It sounds like you should be changing the output directory of your Child project. Set the output directory of your Child directory to your Parent's Bin directory. That way, any time it builds just the Child project, it will be using the latest when you run the Parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup same Child and Parent output directories (for example ..\bin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)).

Also you can add dependency on Child in parent ("Project Dependencies" in Parent context menu). And then setup Parent as startup project. This will make VS to build changed child each time you Press F5.

After all it seems logical to setup project dependency since the Parent depends on Child (no matter at runtime or link time).